# Closing <script>

Tags: javascript, tags

This is a stupid question, and I am aware that it is; but never the less, here it comes:

Is it possible to close a `<script>`-tag within itself, so to speak? I mean if you are using an *external javascript-document* can you close the tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxx.js" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Comment: Hmm... I never came across that one... Sorry for the duplication!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware of it, no.

Browsers usually ignore self closing `script` tags.

Comment: This is where I had originally read this: http://webkit.org/blog/1273/the-html5-parsing-algorithm/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this topic
[Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 0):

If the document is XHTML served as XML, then yes, that's perfectly valid. If you're serving XHTML as HTML, however, [it's not recommended](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_3) as the SGML-style parsers that browsers use to processes tag-soup HTML may have a problem with it. (If you do decide to use self-closing `script` tags like that, be sure and test in several browsers first!)

Comment: Curses, I knew they'd find me here eventually! :)